# FullCalendar issue with moment (1407)

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

Those of you working with the above mentioned, know the warning that is displayed:

*Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.*

Didn't make much of it but it turns out quite important.

This issue above is now causing js errors that Chrome doesn't actually detect. I'm trying to get the current date in fullCalendar, the following function doesn't work:

```
function getCalDate() {
var moment = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
alert(moment.format());
}
```

(It's worth nothing it USED to work, I even reverted back to an older working backup, same problem as bellow)
I get Uncaught [TypeError: moment.format is not a function]. I do have moment.format() in few of the other functions in that page. Basically alert() doesn't work, does not alert...

Can't debug because of this, some of my JS works, some does not any fix suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the question exactly? Can you please give more info on `causing js errors that Chrome doesn't actually detect`?

Comment: wrap the dates in a moment before they go in and re-wrap the one from `getDate` like `alert(moment(moment).format())`. If that doesn't fix it, `console.log` the moment you get from `getDate` and tell us (or screenshot) what the object looks like in the console. I have a suspicion that this will clear up the problem.

Comment: @slicedtoad   
m.fn.init[1]     0: div#calendar.fc.fc-ltr.ui-widget     context: document  length: 1     selector: "#calendar"__     proto__: m[0]

Comment: Could you edit that into your answer? Specifically, give the line of code you ran and the result.

Comment: @slicedtoad Yeah, noticed it is formatted like crap: http://i.imgur.com/TBjHAx5.png Alert commented out as it didn't work.

Comment: ... That's a jquery object. I have no idea why that would be returned. Ok, what you need to do is create a [mcve]. See how _little_ code you can use to reproduce the problem and then post the code or a JSFiddle. Start by cutting out all the code except for the date initialization and the `getDate` and see if that reproduces it. This is required on SO for this kind of question. And if it's a bug, the fullCalendar author needs this in a bug report too.

Comment: Just an FYI. I somewhat "restarted" the calendar, removed quite a lot of the code I had written since it was working fully and then the date started appearing. I held Ctrl+Z reentering the code to the state it was when i asked the question, and the date still worked ... I will go ahead and assume i have a bigger issue somewhere else (Since i used to have alerts not showing too). Thank to everyone who participated.